# OcList and dism alternative on ws2008 sp2

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a way to list all installed features in the console (cmd.exe). I have ws2008 without OcList.exe and without dism.exe installed. I have to list it in console view.

Comment: Dism.exe is not available on Ws2008. i am still locking for an alternative too.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell `Get-WindowsFeature` is what you want. Standard pipline filtering can be applied to only get features that are/aren't installed, or with a certain name, etc.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature

Display Name                                            Name
------------                                            ----
[ ] Active Directory Certificate Services               AD-Certificate
    [ ] Certification Authority                         ADCS-Cert-Authority
    [ ] Certification Authority Web Enrollment          ADCS-Web-Enrollment
    [ ] Online Responder                                ADCS-Online-Cert
    [ ] Network Device Enrollment Service               ADCS-Device-Enrollment
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Web Service              ADCS-Enroll-Web-Svc
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service       ADCS-Enroll-Web-Pol
[ ] Active Directory Domain Services                    AD-Domain-Services
    [ ] Active Directory Domain Controller              ADDS-Domain-Controller
    [ ] Identity Management for UNIX                    ADDS-Identity-Mgmt
        [ ] Server for Network Information Services     ADDS-NIS
        [ ] Password Synchronization                    ADDS-Password-Sync
        [ ] Administration Tools                        ADDS-IDMU-Tools
[ ] Active Directory Federation Services                AD-Federation-Services
    [ ] Federation Service                              ADFS-Federation
    [ ] Federation Service Proxy                        ADFS-Proxy
    [ ] AD FS Web Agents                                ADFS-Web-Agents
        [ ] Claims-aware Agent                          ADFS-Claims
        [ ] Windows Token-based Agent                   ADFS-Windows-Token
[ ] Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services     ADLDS
[ ] Active Directory Rights Management Services         ADRMS
    [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Server       ADRMS-Server
    [ ] Identity Federation Support                     ADRMS-Identity
[ ] Application Server                                  Application-Server
    [ ] .NET Framework 3.5.1                            AS-NET-Framework
    [ ] Web Server (IIS) Support                        AS-Web-Support
    [ ] COM+ Network Access                             AS-Ent-Services
    [ ] TCP Port Sharing                                AS-TCP-Port-Sharing
    [ ] Windows Process Activation Service Support      AS-WAS-Support
        [ ] HTTP Activation                             AS-HTTP-Activation
        [ ] Message Queuing Activation                  AS-MSMQ-Activation
        [ ] TCP Activation                              AS-TCP-Activation
        [ ] Named Pipes Activation                      AS-Named-Pipes
    [ ] Distributed Transactions                        AS-Dist-Transaction
        [ ] Incoming Remote Transactions                AS-Incoming-Trans
        [ ] Outgoing Remote Transactions                AS-Outgoing-Trans
        [ ] WS-Atomic Transactions                      AS-WS-Atomic
[ ] DHCP Server                                         DHCP
[ ] DNS Server                                          DNS
[ ] Fax Server                                          Fax
[ ] File Services                                       File-Services
    [ ] File Server                                     FS-FileServer
    [ ] Distributed File System                         FS-DFS
        [ ] DFS Namespaces                              FS-DFS-Namespace
        [ ] DFS Replication                             FS-DFS-Replication
    [ ] File Server Resource Manager                    FS-Resource-Manager
    [ ] Services for Network File System                FS-NFS-Services
    [ ] Windows Search Service                          FS-Search-Service
    [ ] Windows Server 2003 File Services               FS-Win2003-Services
        [ ] Indexing Service                            FS-Indexing-Service
    [ ] BranchCache for network files                   FS-BranchCache
[ ] Hyper-V                                             Hyper-V
[ ] Network Policy and Access Services                  NPAS
    [ ] Network Policy Server                           NPAS-Policy-Server
    [ ] Routing and Remote Access Services              NPAS-RRAS-Services
        [ ] Remote Access Service                       NPAS-RRAS
        [ ] Routing                                     NPAS-Routing
    [ ] Health Registration Authority                   NPAS-Health
    [ ] Host Credential Authorization Protocol          NPAS-Host-Cred
[X] Print and Document Services                         Print-Services
    [X] Print Server                                    Print-Server
    [ ] LPD Service                                     Print-LPD-Service
    [ ] Internet Printing                               Print-Internet
    [ ] Distributed Scan Server                         Print-Scan-Server
[X] Remote Desktop Services                             Remote-Desktop-Services
    [X] Remote Desktop Session Host                     RDS-RD-Server
    [ ] Remote Desktop Virtualization Host              RDS-Virtualization
        [ ] Core Services                               RDS-Virtualization-Core
        [ ] RemoteFX                                    RDS-RemoteFX
    [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing                        RDS-Licensing
    [ ] Remote Desktop Connection Broker                RDS-Connection-Broker
    [ ] Remote Desktop Gateway                          RDS-Gateway
    [ ] Remote Desktop Web Access                       RDS-Web-Access
[ ] Web Server (IIS)                                    Web-Server
    [ ] Web Server                                      Web-WebServer
        [ ] Common HTTP Features                        Web-Common-Http
            [ ] Static Content                          Web-Static-Content
            [ ] Default Document                        Web-Default-Doc
            [ ] Directory Browsing                      Web-Dir-Browsing
            [ ] HTTP Errors                             Web-Http-Errors
            [ ] HTTP Redirection                        Web-Http-Redirect
            [ ] WebDAV Publishing                       Web-DAV-Publishing
        [ ] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev
            [ ] ASP.NET                                 Web-Asp-Net
            [ ] .NET Extensibility                      Web-Net-Ext
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI
            [ ] ISAPI Extensions                        Web-ISAPI-Ext
            [ ] ISAPI Filters                           Web-ISAPI-Filter
            [ ] Server Side Includes                    Web-Includes
        [ ] Health and Diagnostics                      Web-Health
            [ ] HTTP Logging                            Web-Http-Logging
            [ ] Logging Tools                           Web-Log-Libraries
            [ ] Request Monitor                         Web-Request-Monitor
            [ ] Tracing                                 Web-Http-Tracing
            [ ] Custom Logging                          Web-Custom-Logging
            [ ] ODBC Logging                            Web-ODBC-Logging
        [ ] Security                                    Web-Security
            [ ] Basic Authentication                    Web-Basic-Auth
            [ ] Windows Authentication                  Web-Windows-Auth
            [ ] Digest Authentication                   Web-Digest-Auth
            [ ] Client Certificate Mapping Authentic... Web-Client-Auth
            [ ] IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authe... Web-Cert-Auth
            [ ] URL Authorization                       Web-Url-Auth
            [ ] Request Filtering                       Web-Filtering
            [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions              Web-IP-Security
        [ ] Performance                                 Web-Performance
            [ ] Static Content Compression              Web-Stat-Compression
            [ ] Dynamic Content Compression             Web-Dyn-Compression
    [ ] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools
        [ ] IIS Management Console                      Web-Mgmt-Console
        [ ] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools
        [ ] Management Service                          Web-Mgmt-Service
        [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility              Web-Mgmt-Compat
            [ ] IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility            Web-Metabase
            [ ] IIS 6 WMI Compatibility                 Web-WMI
            [ ] IIS 6 Scripting Tools                   Web-Lgcy-Scripting
            [ ] IIS 6 Management Console                Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console
    [ ] FTP Server                                      Web-Ftp-Server
        [ ] FTP Service                                 Web-Ftp-Service
        [ ] FTP Extensibility                           Web-Ftp-Ext
    [ ] IIS Hostable Web Core                           Web-WHC
[ ] Windows Deployment Services                         WDS
    [ ] Deployment Server                               WDS-Deployment
    [ ] Transport Server                                WDS-Transport
[ ] Windows Server Update Services                      OOB-WSUS
[X] .NET Framework 3.5.1 Features                       NET-Framework
    [X] .NET Framework 3.5.1                            NET-Framework-Core
    [ ] WCF Activation                                  NET-Win-CFAC
        [ ] HTTP Activation                             NET-HTTP-Activation
        [ ] Non-HTTP Activation                         NET-Non-HTTP-Activ
[ ] Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS)      BITS
    [ ] Compact Server                                  BITS-Compact-Server
    [ ] IIS Server Extension                            BITS-IIS-Ext
[ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption                          BitLocker
[ ] BranchCache                                         BranchCache
[ ] Connection Manager Administration Kit               CMAK
[X] Desktop Experience                                  Desktop-Experience
[ ] DirectAccess Management Console                     DAMC
[ ] Failover Clustering                                 Failover-Clustering
[ ] Group Policy Management                             GPMC
[X] Ink and Handwriting Services                        Ink-Handwriting
    [X] Ink Support                                     IH-Ink-Support
    [ ] Handwriting Recognition                         IH-Handwriting
[ ] Internet Printing Client                            Internet-Print-Client
[ ] Internet Storage Name Server                        ISNS
[ ] LPR Port Monitor                                    LPR-Port-Monitor
[ ] Message Queuing                                     MSMQ
    [ ] Message Queuing Services                        MSMQ-Services
        [ ] Message Queuing Server                      MSMQ-Server
        [ ] Directory Service Integration               MSMQ-Directory
        [ ] Message Queuing Triggers                    MSMQ-Triggers
        [ ] HTTP Support                                MSMQ-HTTP-Support
        [ ] Multicasting Support                        MSMQ-Multicasting
        [ ] Routing Service                             MSMQ-Routing
    [ ] Message Queuing DCOM Proxy                      MSMQ-DCOM
[ ] Multipath I/O                                       Multipath-IO
[ ] Network Load Balancing                              NLB
[ ] Peer Name Resolution Protocol                       PNRP
[ ] Quality Windows Audio Video Experience              qWave
[ ] Remote Assistance                                   Remote-Assistance
[ ] Remote Differential Compression                     RDC
[X] Remote Server Administration Tools                  RSAT
    [X] Role Administration Tools                       RSAT-Role-Tools
        [ ] Active Directory Certificate Services Tools RSAT-ADCS
            [ ] Certification Authority Tools           RSAT-ADCS-Mgmt
            [ ] Online Responder Tools                  RSAT-Online-Responder
        [ ] AD DS and AD LDS Tools                      RSAT-AD-Tools
            [ ] AD DS Tools                             RSAT-ADDS
                [ ] AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line ... RSAT-ADDS-Tools
                [ ] Active Directory Administrative ... RSAT-AD-AdminCenter
                [ ] Server for NIS Tools                RSAT-SNIS
            [ ] AD LDS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools  RSAT-ADLDS
            [ ] Active Directory module for Windows ... RSAT-AD-PowerShell
        [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Servi... RSAT-RMS
        [ ] DHCP Server Tools                           RSAT-DHCP
        [ ] DNS Server Tools                            RSAT-DNS-Server
        [ ] Fax Server Tools                            RSAT-Fax
        [X] File Services Tools                         RSAT-File-Services
            [X] Distributed File System Tools           RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con
            [ ] File Server Resource Manager Tools      RSAT-FSRM-Mgmt
            [ ] Services for Network File System Tools  RSAT-NFS-Admin
        [ ] Hyper-V Tools                               RSAT-Hyper-V
        [ ] Network Policy and Access Services Tools    RSAT-NPAS
        [X] Print and Document Services Tools           RSAT-Print-Services
        [X] Remote Desktop Services Tools               RSAT-RDS
            [X] Remote Desktop Session Host Tools       RSAT-RDS-RemoteApp
            [ ] Remote Desktop Gateway Tools            RSAT-RDS-Gateway
            [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing Tools          RSAT-RDS-Licensing
            [ ] Remote Desktop Connection Broker Tools  RSAT-RDS-Conn-Broker
        [ ] Web Server (IIS) Tools                      RSAT-Web-Server
        [ ] Windows Deployment Services Tools           RSAT-WDS
    [ ] Feature Administration Tools                    RSAT-Feature-Tools
        [ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption Administratio... RSAT-BitLocker
            [ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption Tools        RSAT-Bitlocker-DriveEnc
            [ ] BitLocker Recovery Password Viewer      RSAT-Bitlocker-RecPwd
        [ ] BITS Server Extensions Tools                RSAT-Bits-Server
        [ ] Failover Clustering Tools                   RSAT-Clustering
        [ ] Network Load Balancing Tools                RSAT-NLB
        [ ] SMTP Server Tools                           RSAT-SMTP
        [ ] WINS Server Tools                           RSAT-WINS
[ ] RPC over HTTP Proxy                                 RPC-over-HTTP-Proxy
[ ] Simple TCP/IP Services                              Simple-TCPIP
[ ] SMTP Server                                         SMTP-Server
[ ] SNMP Services                                       SNMP-Services
    [ ] SNMP Service                                    SNMP-Service
    [ ] SNMP WMI Provider                               SNMP-WMI-Provider
[ ] Storage Manager for SANs                            Storage-Mgr-SANS
[ ] Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications               Subsystem-UNIX-Apps
[X] Telnet Client                                       Telnet-Client
[ ] Telnet Server                                       Telnet-Server
[ ] TFTP Client                                         TFTP-Client
[ ] Windows Biometric Framework                         Biometric-Framework
[ ] Windows Internal Database                           Windows-Internal-DB
[ ] Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environm... PowerShell-ISE
[ ] Windows Process Activation Service                  WAS
    [ ] Process Model                                   WAS-Process-Model
    [ ] .NET Environment                                WAS-NET-Environment
    [ ] Configuration APIs                              WAS-Config-APIs
[X] Windows Server Backup Features                      Backup-Features
    [X] Windows Server Backup                           Backup
    [X] Command-line Tools                              Backup-Tools
[ ] Windows Server Migration Tools                      Migration
[ ] Windows System Resource Manager                     WSRM
[ ] Windows TIFF IFilter                                TIFF-IFilter
[ ] WinRM IIS Extension                                 WinRM-IIS-Ext
[ ] WINS Server                                         WINS-Server
[ ] Wireless LAN Service                                Wireless-Networking
[ ] XPS Viewer                                          XPS-Viewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but all of the installed Roles and Features are cleary visible in the Server Manager mmc console.

Comment: It must be in the console (cmd.exe or powershell)